# How to Make iMacros Run Data Entry Script for 100's of CSV's?

Tags: imacros

I have a script that will run the same exact process (pasting a list from a CSV into a text box), many times on the same web page, and I'm trying to get it to run the process one time for many CSV's in the working folder (1.csv, 2.csv, 3.csv,... 100.csv, etc).

**Is it possible for iMacros to loop through the same script, only varying the input file (!DATASOURCE)?**

I will name the CSV's numerically so the script can cycle through them easily.

[Link to sample CSV](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByUcHTNcynugQnd6NkRCR3F2VjQ/view?usp=sharing) (note: all keywords  put into 1 cell so that it can be pasted as a list, one per line).

Example of how each CSV file's contents will be pasted as a list (one keyword per line):
[image: Example of how data will be pasted]

I am new to iMacros and was hoping this would work, but it stops running on the 2nd loop, and throws the error: 
`TypeError: this.dataSource[(line - 1)] is undefined, line 14 (Error code: -1001)`

Here is the code I have so far:

```
VERSION BUILD=8961227 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1

SET !DATASOURCE {{!LOOP}}.csv

URL GOTO=https://sellercentral.amazon.com/hz/cm/adgroup/create?campaignId=A0478490D2AQYA9C8NTW
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:product-search-results
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SEARCH FORM=ID:form-ad-group ATTR=ID:product-search-input CONTENT=product<SP>name
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:form-ad-group ATTR=ID:product-search-button
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:form-ad-group ATTR=TXT:Select
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:form-ad-group ATTR=ID:txt-starting-bid CONTENT=1.25
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:tool-kw-ui-manual
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:form-ad-group ATTR=ID:txt-keywords CONTENT={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:Add<SP>these<SP>keywordsSaving...
```

**Note:**
I'm trying to automate data entry of a list, and since the data needed to be pasted one keyword per line, I had to save my list with notepad as a .csv and put quotation marks before the first keyword, and after the last keyword, so iMacros would recognize it as just 1 cell.

Answer (score 0):

Just realized my approach was valid, just didn't realize I had to put the `SET !DATASOURCE_LINE 1` after `SET !DATASOURCE {{!LOOP}}.csv`

The working code I have now looks like this:

```
VERSION BUILD=8961227 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1

SET !DATASOURCE {{!LOOP}}.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE 1

URL GOTO=https://sellercentral.amazon.com/hz/cm/adgroup/create?campaignId=A0478490D2AQYA9C8NTW
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:product-search-results
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SEARCH FORM=ID:form-ad-group ATTR=ID:product-search-input CONTENT=product<SP>name
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:form-ad-group ATTR=ID:product-search-button
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:form-ad-group ATTR=TXT:Select
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:form-ad-group ATTR=ID:txt-starting-bid CONTENT=1.25
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:tool-kw-ui-manual
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:form-ad-group ATTR=ID:txt-keywords CONTENT={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:Add<SP>these<SP>keywordsSaving...
```